# Google drive style excel download in angularJS

Tags: filesaver.js

How can I provide google drive type excel download functionality in my site developed in angularJS? I am currently using filesaver.js but it does not work on MacBook Safari. I checked google drive is able to download excel files correctly. Any pointers??

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#safari-61) relevant?

Comment: So you think it's not a question? Or I put wrong tags!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the [tag:google-drive-sdk] is irrelevant because you aren't actually using the Google Drive SDK. I would guess that the [tag:jquery] and [tag:angularjs] tags are also irrelevant, because (I suspect) the issue has nothing to do with jQuery or Angular. I would suggest creating a page that only uses Filesaver.js and nothing else, and see what happens. Also, are there any console errors?

Comment: Thanks@ZevSpitz, I removed unwanted tags. Using just filesaver.js doesnot help, since it uses download attribute of browser which safari doesnot supports and its confirmed on filesaver github as well.

Comment: If the files are hosted in your Google Drive then yes, you can certainly use Drive API to download the file. This is stated in the 
[Download Files guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads). But if it's not, then you're looking for a different library or tool.

Comment: Yes my files are generated at client side only using filesaver.js but that doesn't works in safari, they use download attribute which is not supported yet in safari.so I am looking for any other way of downloading these excel files